# Android - Matcher.find() infinite

Tags: android, regex, replace

I have implemented AsyncTask where the regular expression provided by the user is being used for matching huge html-code data. However, because some of the regular expressions contain a lot of quantifiers/backtracking, Matcher.find() goes infinite.

I have tried to use **InterruptibleCharSequence** provided here: [How to terminate Matcher.find(), when its running too long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125732/how-to-terminate-matcher-find-when-its-running-too-long), but it seems that *charAt* is never get called, so never interrupted. My last guess is to create a new process just to run this regular matching procedure and then kill it when searching is cancelled. However, then I have a problem with sharing objects between Service and Activity, because of different processes.

Answer (score -3):

Parsing HTML using RegEx is a bad idea, see: [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

What about parsing the DOM instead? I tried [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) a while ago and found it pretty neat to work with.