# Java Runaway Regular Expression: Catastrophic Backtracking

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone explain to me why my regular expression:

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s(.+?)+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)|[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\.\s[a-zA-Z+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)|[a-zA-Z]+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)|[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)
```

With input:

```
Testės r. sav., Žtestčių Vhest sen., Platakių k.
```

is causing catastrophic Backtracking?

On the other hand, if I add ^ and $, like:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s(.+?)+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)|[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\.\s[a-zA-Z+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)|[a-zA-Z]+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)|[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)$
```

There is no backtracking.

(tested with regex101.com)

However, when I try to use regular expression (^$ included) with Java:

```
Matcher matcher = myRegexPattern.matcher(string);
if(matcher.find()){
    //
}
```

Backtrack persists... Any ideas how to avoid backtrack using java?

Comment: have you escaped special characters when introducing `String` in Java? i.e. `\\\`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The main idea: write  a *linear* regex. Note that all the branches in your alternation pattern can match at the same location - that increases redundant backtracking. Also, you seem to have a missing `]` at `[a-zA-Z+\s(?:pr.|g.|a.)` and the `+` at `(.+?)+` looks like a real culprit.

Comment: This regular expression should return nothing, matcher.find() should return false. I escaped every `[` in regular expression, and it works...any idea why? I mean string doesn't even have `[` character.

Comment: As for missing `]`, that's copy/paste error.

Comment: Side note on code quality: if you think your regex gives you a hard time, right now, while you are in the midst of developing it ... what exactly do you expect to happen when you have to slightly change it in a few weeks, because of a subtle change in your requirements? In other words: maybe, sometimes, there are better ways to parse strings than one huge monster regex?!

Comment: @Jägermeister I wish there was a better way to parse it, unfortunately there is not (or I can't figure out a better way at least)

Comment: The way you have the regex now, `[a-zA-Z]+\s(.+?)\s(?:(?:pr|g|a)\.)` should work for you.

Comment: Have you tried the expression I suggested? Does it fix your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it does not fix my issue. While it fixes backtrack issue, it doesn't give correct output. Example: `Testės r. sav., Žtestčių Vhest sen., Platakių g.` should return `Platakių g.`, instead your regex returns `r. sav., Žtestčių Vhest sen., Platakių g.` I solved this problem based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910740/cancelling-a-long-running-regex-match

Comment: That is not a fix, that is a workaround. If you are interested in a fix, please add the specifications to the question in order to write a correct and efficient pattern. [Your regex will match `s r. sav., Žtestčių Vhest sen., Platakių g.`](https://regex101.com/r/jM0xX3/1), not `Platakių g.`

Comment: The current regex you have can be just reduced to `[a-zA-Z]+\s(?:(.+?)\s)?(?:(?:pr|g|a)\.)|[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\.\s[a-zA-Z]+\s(?:(?:pr|g|a)\.)` and it does not make much sense.