# Java regex parser without stack overflow

Tags: java, regex, exception

Handling a regex with `java.util.regex` leads to a stack overflow for large strings and complicated regex (especially with `|` in it).

Is there a way to handle regular expressions more defensively in Java, like

- having a non-recursive mode for regex
- throwing a catchable exception for those regular expressions (instead of a java.lang.Stackoverflow error),

or any other mechanism that does not kill my program or put it in an unrecoverable state?

Comment: I advise you to try simplifying the regex instead of finding a solution for the stack overflow error.

Comment: True, this is often sensible. But it is actually annoying to come up with a regular expression, let it pass all the unit tests, put it in a large analysis program to see it crash at 2am because some input string was really large.

Comment: This answer has been answered several times. Implement some timeout mechanism: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910740/cancelling-a-long-running-regex-match

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: True, this is a reasonable approach, but also unsatisfying because I have to guess a time limit depending on my stack size. My programs are usually running at night to do some kind of job. I do not care whether a regex takes 5 minutes as long as it does not crash the JVM.

Comment: What are you trying to do in your program? May be you are seeing the problem from a different angle.

Comment: Solutiontwo: only use regexps that are writtdn acc. to unroll the loop principle, linearly, where each preceding subpattern cannot match the same character as the subsequent subpattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `StackOverflowError` can be caught and handled just as any exception. Errors signals serious problems that you normally should not catch, but in this case you know what it is and you need to handle it. Just catch it and handle the situation (or re-throw a custom exception).

You might also want to consider using the `-Xss` command line flag to increase your stack size.

Comment: I agree with second part. First part seems a bit sketchy.. handling a run time error is working around actual issue. It looks to me that the  user should valid input and rethink the expressions based on requirement if that is causing run time errors.

Comment: Yes, @ringbearer, I agree with you, best is to _avoid_ the problem, at least if it can be done at a reasonable cost. In this case, I want to offer a way to prevent damage, which could be a starting point, while waiting for a better solution (which may or may not come)...

Comment: The only correct solution: *only use regexps that are written acc. to unroll the loop principle, linearly, where each preceding subpattern cannot match the same character as the subsequent subpattern.*